# How to calculate the start date and end date of next week based on current date in apex

Tags: apex, class

Formula to get the start date and end date of next week based on current date in apex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is direct way. But you can do this.

```
date myDate = date.today();
date weekStart = myDate.toStartofWeek();
system.debug(weekStart.addDays(7) );
```

It will return the start of the week for the Date that called the method, depending on the context user's locale. example, the start of a week is Sunday in the United States locale, and Monday in European locales.